# Unable to sync node with testnet

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, testnets

I am trying to sync my node with testnest rpc with following command.
`geth --testnet --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024  --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303"`

But it is just stuck after starting a localhost server. Here is the screenshot of my terminal.
[image]

When i try to sysnc with just `geth` command its syncing fine. Anyone having idea what's wrong here?

Comment: Let me know issue is resolved?

Comment: @JitendraKumar.Balla is resolved. i changes the boot node from https://gist.github.com/rfikki/c895641b6405c082f68bcf139cf2f7ae and its syncing fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess 13.84.180.240, 52.169.14.227 boot nodes are down. As per eth logs its trying to dial again and again.

Add `--verbosity` option along with your command it will tell whats wrong/currently whats geth is doing.

```
geth --testnet --verbosity 6 --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024  --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303"
```

`--verbosity` value starts from 0 to 6.

If you want to set logs to be default then

geth attach  then type debug.verbosity(3) it will reset to default.

Comment: ahhh. thanks mate. your were right, those boot nodes were down. changes the boot node and now syncing fine

Comment: @ShoaibIqbal Can you please accept my ans, It will help community to solve issues.